# Eclipse/Hibernate tools error: Archive classpath entry doesn't exist

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to setup Hibernate tools – attaching it to the spring petclinic project.  So far the problem is in classpath.  My actions:

- Click on hibernate on the Hibernate Configuration view
- Add
  postgresql-9.1.jar located in the root directory of the
  spring-petclinic project

The result is the error: [Classpath]: Archive classpath entry doesn't exist [/spring-petclinic/postgresql-9.1.jar] ( see http://jboston.net/HIbernateToolsError.jpg for the image)

See also the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /postgresql-9.1.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /postgresql-9.1.jar
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2170)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFile(Container.java:208)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.utils.ProjectUtils.findJavaProjects(ProjectUtils.java:308)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.ProjectCompilerVersionChecker.validateProjectComplianceLevel(ProjectCompilerVersionChecker.java:35)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.java:37)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:100)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Craig Ringer answer helped.  My workaround was as follows:

- Create the user library with a postgresql jdbc jar
- From the Hibernate configuration classpath tab select Advanced on the
  right menu
- Choose "Add library"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've attempted to add the JDBC jar as a required project. Don't. Add it as a library dependency instead.

See [this list of ways to do it](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) - unverified, as I thankfully no longer have to use Eclipse anymore.

Comment: Maybe I do not undestand somethimg. The question was about adding the postgres jar to Hibernate tools, not to the project

Comment: @anarinsky The log doesn't seem to match the error message. The error suggests the jar is missing; the log suggests it's trying to add a jar as if it was a project directory. Both suggest it's being added as a dependency to an Eclipse project or resource.